Facing issue while saving updated data back into excel in Streamlit
I'm developing a financial assessment tool in Streamlit where users input data that automatically updates corresponding cells in an integrated financial model (an Excel file). The tool successfully updates the targeted cells and the Excel file reflects these changes. However, when I try to reload the workbook elsewhere in the code, the data appears empty unless I manually save the Excel file. I would like to automate this saving step.
And also this file has multiple sheets and in each sheet have multiple complex formulas which are doing calculations based upon user inputs
Python 3.12.3,
openpyxl: 3.1.5,
streamlit:1.39.0
Pandas: 2.2.3
OS: Unbuntu
main.py
    file_extension = Path(file_path).suffix.lower()[1:]
    if file_extension in ['xlsx', 'xls']:
        workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
        sheet = workbook['Inp_C']

        if st.button("Save Changes"):
            sheet.cell(row=11, column=11, value=st.session_state.fcp2)
            sheet.cell(row=14, column=11, value=st.session_state.field35)
            sheet.cell(row=15, column=11, value=st.session_state.field36)  
            sheet.cell(row=20, column=11, value=st.session_state.field38) 
            sheet.cell(row=25, column=11, value=st.session_state.drtp2) 
            sheet.cell(row=30, column=11, value=st.session_state.cepsp2) 
            sheet.cell(row=31, column=11, value=st.session_state.ces2  / 100) 
            sheet.cell(row=37, column=11, value=st.session_state.field40 / 100) 
            sheet.cell(row=41, column=11, value=st.session_state.upfp2 / 100) 
            sheet.cell(row=44, column=11, value=st.session_state.cfp2 / 100) 
            sheet.cell(row=47, column=11, value=st.session_state.field42 / 100) 
            sheet.cell(row=48, column=11, value=st.session_state.field43 / 100) 
            sheet.cell(row=62, column=11, value=st.session_state.cgp2) 
            sheet.cell(row=63, column=11, value=st.session_state.cfltp2)   
            sheet.cell(row=64, column=11, value=st.session_state.ogsgp2) 
            sheet.cell(row=65, column=11, value=st.session_state.ofo2) 
            sheet.cell(row=68, column=11, value=st.session_state.field53) 
            sheet.cell(row=69, column=11, value=st.session_state.field62) 
            sheet.cell(row=70, column=11, value=st.session_state.field58) 
            sheet.cell(row=71, column=11, value=st.session_state.field59) 
            sheet.cell(row=78, column=11, value=st.session_state.field45 / 100)
            sheet.cell(row=79, column=11, value=st.session_state.field46 / 100)
            sheet.cell(row=84, column=11, value=st.session_state.ofwaccp2  / 100)
            sheet.cell(row=86, column=11, value=st.session_state.drcitrp2 / 100)

            workbook.save(file_path)

            workbook.close()
        else:
            st.write("No changes have been made.")


        #Here I'm try to load the updated model for debugging, but I'm getting cells value empty which are calculating by formula
        df = load_financial_model(file_path,sheet_name='Output',header=None)

        st.write(df)

After researching, I found that xlwings could help, but it only works on Windows and MacOS, while my tool runs on Linux (deployed on Streamlit Cloud). Is there a way to automate saving the Excel file on Linux without having to switch to a Windows-based server?

What do you mean by automatically saving the excel file? You could just remove the button, I guess that should work

Just a general comment; Openpyxl will not open a file with an extension .xls, even if its actually a XLSX file with an incorrect extension name.

Also not entirely source of what you are asking but seems your question may relate to entering formulas into cells and not having these evaluated unless you open then save the Excel file in Excel. This is expected with Openpyxl as its just an XML editor for Excel XLSX files and does not evaluate formulas added to cells, that is done by the Excel app. As you say XLwings would be an option however as it does run the Excel app it cannot run on Linux.

Therefore you options are limited if sticking with Linux and as Openpyxl also does not separate the cell value between Formula and Value you cannot enter a formula into a cell and then update the value. There are some modules like Koala or Pycel that do calculate Excel formulas without Excel whether these would help I cannot say, I have very little experience with the modules. There is also this doc Python tools for Excel dated 2020 which lists Python tools that might also help

To reduce complexity, I have switched to a Windows server. Thank you all for your suggestions and solutions. I’ll reopen this conversation if I encounter any issues on Windows
